# Showing alert for errors with Swift 4

Tags: swift, error-handling

The following code gives me an sigabort when .present is called:

```
    func alert(message: String, title: String = "") {

        let alertController =  UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style {
                case .default:
                    print("default")
                case .cancel:
                    print("cancel")
                case .destructive:
                    print("destructive")
            }}))
        alertController.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Help!  I am not getting this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the alertController's present instead of the view's. Change it to refer to the parent UIViewController's present(...).

```
func present(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, 
    animated flag: Bool, 
  completion: (() -> Void)? = nil)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present